# I cannot receive post data from a form in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

When posting the html form I can see null in the controller, so I am not able to add a Product to the database. What is wrong here?

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}





    public ActionResult CreateProduct()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateProduct(Product product) // this is always null
    {
        service.CreateProduct(product);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }



@model WebApplication1.Models.Product

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateProduct";
}

<h2>CreateProduct</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

        <input type="submit" value="Create" />

    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Show us the Product class code

Comment: I checked your code in an empty MVC project, and everything works fine (i.e. the `product` is not null).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your get pass the model with empty values

```
public ActionResult CreateProduct()
{
    Product prd= new Product();
    return View(prd);
}
```

and check if this solves your problem